# Partial Differential Equation $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} p(x,t) = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} \left[ x^2 p(x,t) \right]$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

In my research I have come across the partial differential equation 
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} p(x,t) = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}
 \left[ x^2 p(x,t) \right]. 
\end{equation}
Although I basically know how to solve such an equation, I would rather have a reference to a paper (due to limited space in journal). 
I assume that this must be a rather well-known equation with well-known solutions.
Does this type of equation have a name? Does somebody know a paper where it is solved?

Comment: it's nearly a diffusion equation...

Comment: This would be a 1D diffusion equation in an inhomogeneous medium--the diffusion is more rapid away from zero than it is close to zero.

Answer (score 2):

It's a 1-D Fokker-Planck equation with a Diffusion proportional to $x^2$ and $0$ drift term.

You can equally consider it as an imaginary time 1-D Schroedinger equation for a unit-charged particle coupled to an classical vector potential $A =\text{contstant} \times x$, choosing the Coulomb gauge. By the way, this problem has a well known analytical solution...

Comment: thanks! Where can I find that solution?